# What's this 1607 Hispania coin?

Tags: spain, spanish-empire, numismatics

[image]

What's this coin called? i found it on a shipwreck website.

Comment: Which shipwreck website?

Answer (score 9):

It looks to me more like an [Escudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_escudo) than a piece of eight.
This [web page](https://coinquest.com/cgi-bin/cq/coins.pl?coin=7468) identifies it as  1 escudo piece, worth possibly $2,500 nowadays.

At the time of minting, [it seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_real), an Escudo was worth 16 Reales.  A piece of eight was worth 8 Reales.